# hot to 'build' a react project for tizen os

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, tizen

im  building a **react** app for tizen (**samsung TV**) when im doing 'npm run build'
it gives me the error "tizen is undefined" and becuase of that im not able to build the app for producution and run it on tizen studio

i added webapck.config.js as said in this link : [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) but without any success

my webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./public/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {

            },
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|ttf|mp4|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {},
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass|css)$/,
        use: [
            "style-loader", // creates style nodes from JS strings
            "css-loader", // translates CSS into CommonJS
            "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS, using Node Sass by default
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  optimization: {

  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: 'dist/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'bundle.map'

  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    htmlPlugin
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    hot: true
  }
};
```

my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "portal-games",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dist": "webpack"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share more of your codebase. I assume it's rather an error in your codebase than in the webpack config.

Comment: @sebastian-ruehmann what do you mean by more code, what files do you want?

Answer (score 2):

If your developing an application for tizen i think the best approach is to use this [renative](https://renative.org/) it will simplfy a lot of the build process and also you can port you existing code with no issues after this you can use

**rnv run -p --tizen** once your set up everything